# Bevel modifier stops to work for diagonal faces

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Here the bevel modifier works well:
[image]

But moving the selected edge, which would perfectly work for a non-beveled shape, makes the bevel progressively enlarge one of its curves, even if the mathematics say that the enlargement should be much smaller:
[image]

The object is symmetric towards a YZ plane. The bevel has options loop slide/angle/arc/shape/grid fill. With other options, as far as I tested, it works similarly or worse.

Is it possible to have the shape well-beveled in Blender 2.82?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

There are a couple of things to try here.

First, select everything in edit mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. Sometimes Blender gets the direction the vertices are facing confused, and this causes issue with beveling.

Second, try and get rid of the 'ngons', aka faces with more than 4 vertices. Beveling ngons is always a bit risky, and when you start moving things around it's not uncommon to see issues pop up. Insetting the ngons with <kbd>I</kbd> is a possible way to get some nice quads along the edge of your bevel.

Comment: I have found that the bevel doesn't work just for any mesh complex enough which I have used. I recalculated normals, removed duplicate vertices. Applying I made either nothing or even more problems. Can it be, Blender's bevel algorithm is good only for simple meshes, otherwise it just fails?

Comment: Bevel usually works pretty well, aside form what I mentioned. Are you able to upload your file? Then I can take a look. You can upload files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Then edit your question and add the link.

Comment: Yes thank you, but can I change the example? In the above, I have finally used a workaround by tapering the object with a lattice (which is better than the original method) but I have a misbehaving bevel in another place.

Comment: Absolutely. Just make sure the title of the question still fits the example, or update that too.

Comment: The title would need to change so I decided to create a new question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172898/multiple-small-glitches-when-beveling-complex-meshes